# Swiper.js duplicate slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I try to create Swiper.js card with one slide which transform: translate3d on image, unfortunately Swiper duplicate my image and card clipping across when flipping

```
<div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="fg">
              <img src="assets/img/lelay.png" alt="" />
              <img src="assets/img/lelay-title.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="bg">
              <img src="assets/img/shape.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here's Fiddle!

https://jsfiddle.net/arz4t8k9/10/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `backface` of the `bg` and `fg` elements.

You can try to give them `backface-visibility:hidden` so the backface doesn't show, like that:

```
fg, .bg{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

and now there is nothing in the background, but the slide shows just one size until you reach the another side, it will be visible.

If it's not what you want, explain me your goal and I will try to help more.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, actually i want keep backface-visibility visible cause it's kinda cool to see it when slide flipping.

For now i have found this website  https://sirup.online/roll-and-bounce/ who use same slider function and doesn't have this issue (60% of scrollbar).

Thanks for you time

Comment: I think that all the problem comes from `swiper.js` itself, because in the `loop:true` for the swiper it duplicates the slides by a really strange way.
So what you need to play with here, or to search for, is not to change some `html` or `css` but try to figure out what swiper does in the loop status.
And I will search for that too, because it's really annoying me in most of my applications, and if I knew how to configure that, I will let you know.

Comment: I FIND IT ! I have three div in my dom with a range of class when i apply "translate3d" on my image,
    one of these div with the class "swiper-slide-next"is my mirrored image who annoyed me.

    So the solution is to edit swiper.css and add at the end of file.
    
    .swiper-slide-next {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    And TADAAAH no annoying image clipping anymore,
    just remenber to setup "allowTouchMove: 0,"in swiper flip parameter otherwise mirrored image pop in when mouse drag the slide.

Comment: Here's Fiddle with solution https://jsfiddle.net/wjzunfgb/